# Morita equivalence and Morita duality

Tags: category-theory

$\def\rmod{R\text{-Mod}}
\def\modr{\text{Mod-}R}
\def\smod{S\text{-Mod}}
\def\mods{\text{Mod-}S}$
Conventionally,  rings $R$ and $S$ are *Morita equivalent*, if the categories of (left) $R$-modules ($\rmod$)
and (left) $S$-modules ($\smod$) are equivalent categories (via some **covariant** equivalence functor). 
I have decided to look closer into Morita equivalence of rings and for that purpose, I picked up

> K.Morita: Duality for modules and its applications in the theory of
>   rings with minimum condition. *Science reports of the Tokyo Kyoiku
>   Daigaku, Section A*, **6**(150), 83--142

Would someone know whether this is the right paper to look at, for Morita equivalence? I see there material on (Morita) duality: If $D_1:\rmod \to \mods$ and $D_2: \mods\to \rmod$ are **contravariant** category equivalences, then the pair $(D_1, D_2)$ is called a *(Morita) duality*. It looks like the two should be definitely related, but how? Morita equivalence is a covariant functor, while Morita duality is a contravariant equivalence switching the sides. Or should I be looking at a different paper for Morita equivalence of rings?

Comment: Your Tex didn't work.

Comment: Not clear why. Maybe the \bold command does not work, or definitions

Comment: Use the site's markdown to format text. If you don't know the syntax, you can use the formatting buttons above the post to show you what to do. e.g. `*italicized text*` gives *italicized text*.